# What do with Rieman-Stieltjes integral on an interval of a function with infinitely mane discontinuity points?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

If we have a finitely many discontinuity points on an interval, say [a,b] and we want to compute the integral of a function defined on this interval, usually we use the notion of improper integral and split the integral in a sum of integral and then compute each sum as an improper integral itself, but if we wave infinetely many points of discontinuity, what can be done?

Thank you.

Comment: Countably many discontinuities, or uncountably many?

Comment: initialy the countbly ones, but i assume that i am interested also on the uncountably many :)

Answer (score 1):

Even if uncountable, the real question is "what is the measure of the set of discontinuities"?  (Any countable set has measure 0, an uncountable set **may** have measure 0.)  Any set of measure 0 can be ignored.